# Is there any point in upvoting declined feature-requests?

Tags: discussion, up-votes, meta

Is there any point to upvoting a feature request that has been given [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) in the past?

Is there any chance that with enough upvotes it will actually be reconsidered?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, status declined has been reversed on several occasions. [As noted in my answer to this question about supported old requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63051/how-do-i-effectively-support-old-feature-requests/63085#63085), there are [incidents that even long old declined requests ended up implemented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/36049/revisions).

Vote it to show support, also make sure that if you can provide ample evidence that the outlook should be reconsidered, that you do so.

Answer (score 10):

It's always worth upvoting.

If there hasn't been much activity in the past, it might also be worth leaving a comment, or even an answer outlining why the request is still relevant, and should be implemented.

Declined feature requests *have* been revived and implemented in the past - not often, but it has happened.

Answer (score 5):

If the request is something that is contrary to the "spirit" of what we're trying to do, it's probably declined forever.

In other words:

> "you should convert this car into a truck!"

versus

> "this car should have power windows!"

Everything else is debatable, but it's up to you to decide which requests are fundamentally at odds with our philosophy of Q&A.

Comment: If the former isn't [tag:status-bydesign], what is?