# How can I "vote" in favor of already posted feature request?

Tags: feature-request, support

My question is very similar to [How do I effectively support old feature requests?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63051/how-do-i-effectively-support-old-feature-requests), though I do not consider it the exact duplicate.

What can I do to facilitate a particular SO improvement (feature request) that has been already posted by someone else, *other than up-voting it*? Are there any other options?

**EDIT**

RE: Offering bounty for feature request

I'm somewhat confused here.  I believe that decision to implement (or not to implement) a certain new feature belongs to Dev team.  Who I will be offering bounty to?  Fellow members that answer the feature request post?

Please clarify.

Comment: See [How do I get attention for old, unanswered questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions)  The same answers apply to your situation.

Comment: upvote, set a bounty, add content to the request to clarify that there is new evidence making the request important now.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89026/can-we-re-request-features-that-were-declined-a-sufficient-while-ago

Comment: Bribery might work.  Or maybe swag.  We like swag.  Especially if it is emblazoned with unicorns.

Comment: Seriously, though, every software developer shop has priorities and limited resources; convince them that your feature request is more important than all the others.

Comment: @ Robert Harvey - Just for clarification: this is a request posted by *someone else* that already has about 200 up-votes.

Comment: You could've already brought more attention to it by providing a link to the said request here :P

Comment: Your question has prompted me to post this one: [Does the SE development team regularly check the bounty board?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/180063/158605)

Comment: @Rachel - I already posted the below link in a comment to your post, but want to have it here as well:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56010/does-the-team-actually-pay-special-attention-to-featured-questions-on-meta?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Bounty on meta is different than on the main sites since it is more for lobbying... with the aims being:

- garner upvotes (in the hope of the below happening at some time in the future), so as to demonstrate there is a genuine interest in the feature
- a vague hope that someone in the dev team feel excited enough about it to implement it

The implication being that if a request has "enough" upvotes it's more likely to be considered by the devs, however it's *certainly* no guarantee it will be.

Upvoting on meta says: "I think this is a good idea".
Offering a meta-bounty says: "**Look**, I *really* think this is a good idea".

Comment: Having lots of upvotes makes it very likely that it will be *considered* by the dev team.  They're generally pretty good at actually looking at the popular requests with lots of upvotes.  Whether that consideration will result in implementation is unlikely to be too strongly influenced by upvotes.

Comment: Unfortunately, with how long some feature-requests have been around and had time to accumulate votes, I don't think sorting them by votes is very efficient anymore. At best, a bounty is a shot in the dark to try and get someone on the dev team's attention (or the attention of someone that can bring the issue up with the dev team).