# Profiling of 'Hot network questions'

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions

I understand topic of Hot Network Questions was brought up a few times, but the question remains: Will there be any possibility to somewhat profile what is shown up there? I am totally uninterested in couple of categories (for example gaming, role-playing) which always show up, yet I am interested in others which never show up. Some user selectable option would be nice.

Comment: OK, but there was no reply from the crew. What is the status? Where is this going? Is it going anywhere?

Comment: See [How do I effectively support old feature requests?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/63051)

Comment: Opening a new request is not going to generate a status, really. If it's implemented, we'll know. Until then, if it doesn't have a `status-declined` chances are it could be implemented *at some point in the future*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters not really, that old one is about the hot questions tab in multicollider box which is now long gone.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: in the past other side-bar hot-question filtering requests have also been closed as a dupe of that one. It is still about filtering the hot questions list by user preferences, *regardless* of where that list is shown.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: in other words: why does it matter where the list is shown?

Comment: @MartijnPieters because things are changing. In the sidebar of each site, always visible, it gets x100 more attention and it's natural people want to filter it. There is a real dupe, going to look for it now.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: sure, but that means the feature request is now more popular and is getting more votes. Why would a **new** feature request need to be posted? The functionality change is the same.